# Error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] - (_ssl.c:1056) when loading datasets from Keras, macOS Catalina

Tags: python, r, keras, ssl-certificate, macos-catalina

When I tried to download datasets from Keras in R on my Mac (MacOS Catalina), I have this error:

```
> mnist <- dataset_mnist() #Downloading MNIST from Keras

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/Users/jinduong/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/mnist.py", line 49, in load_data
    file_hash='8a61469f7ea1b51cbae51d4f78837e45')
  File "/Users/jinduong/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 250, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
```

So I have an error of [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] with (_ssl.c:1056)

I did try almost, if not all of everything I can find in Google, including (not chronological order):

**1.** Change Python default to 3.8 (the latest one) from Python 2.7

**2.** Try to update Certificate by manually running the file "Install Certificates.command" and "Update Shell Profile.command".

**3.** Try `$ pip install --upgrade certifi`

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its lifeon January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python asPython 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2019.11.28)
```

**4.** Try `bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command`

```
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2019.11.28)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
 -- update complete
```

**5.** Install `request` in terminal

**6.** Clear Chrome cache

And unfortunately, none of them work for me. Strangely, it works just fine on my other Macbook Air with me basically doing nothing. Also, I have very little experience with Unix so I have no clue what I should do.

(PS: I'm using the latest Rstudio-1.2.5033, R version 3.6.2, and my Tensorflow is 1.13.1 as the later version could not work on R with Keras for me)

Comment: `SSL_CERTIFICATE_VERIFIED` means exactly what it says. The place to start is by pulling and inspecting the SSL certificate for `storage.googleapis.com`. Note that Apple recently implemented new rules that limit the maximum lifetime a certificate can have and still be considered valid. It *could* be that the certificate doesn't comply with those rules, or it could be that it's genuinely invalid (and you're under attack by someone at your ISP or who can otherwise monkey-in-the-middle with your network connection).

Comment: ...it's dangerous to assume that you're *not* under attack -- the safe thing to do is to assume that you are (and thus that if you just overrode the check and downloaded from `storage.googleapis.com` instead you'd be getting a library with hostile code added) and try to do a root-cause analysis running down the details. If you come to the conclusion that you aren't after a thorough investigation, _then_ you can safely proceed.

Comment: One place I'd start, btw, is seeing if you get the same behavior from `openssl s_client`. If so, you can immediately rule out any Python-only problem.

Comment: You can also download the content directly in a browser you trust, and then tell pip to install the downloaded file.

Comment: If I just paste your URL in Chrome, Chrome indicates that `The connection to this site is not secure` so either the download URL domain provides an invalid certificate or doesn't provide a certificate at all because your server doesn't have the SSL certificate installed, even though you call the URL with `https`.

Comment: It is more likely that the domain `storage.googleapis.com` is configured with `HTTP` and not `HTTPS` hence not providing any certificate, try to call it with `http` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install certificates via .command files.

go to this path and run the .command file :

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.X/Install\ Certificates.command
```